# Compare lists and get values with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My object is "MyClass" with 2 properties : Id (int) and HourBy (int)

I have two list :

```
var List1 = new List<MyClass>();
var List2 = new List<MyClass>();
```

I'd like to get one list with :
- Object from List1 present in List2 based on Id with Hourby (list2) < Hourby in List1
- Object from List1 no present in List2

```
//#Sample1
//List1 :
List1.add(new MyClass(1,10));
List1.add(new MyClass(2,20));
List1.add(new MyClass(3,30));
//List2 :
List2.add(new MyClass(1,10)); 
List2.add(new MyClass(2,15));
//I'd like to get :
new MyClass(2,5);
new MyClass(3,30);

//Sample2
List1 :
List1.add(new MyClass(1,10));
List1.add(new MyClass(2,20));
List1.add(new MyClass(3,30));
//List2 :
List2.add(new MyClass(1,10)); 
List2.add(new MyClass(2,15));
List2.add(new MyClass(2,2));
//I'd like to get :
new MyClass(2,3);
new MyClass(3,30);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you confirm this is what you want.....You want to return all items in list1 that are present in list2 but have a lower HourBy property value in List2, and all items that are present in List2 but not in List1?

Comment: I agree, the prose explanation is not very clear, but the examples show more clearly the requirement.

I find it interesting to see the different approaches people have used in their answers (although they are not all functionally equivalent)

Comment: @James : let's me try to rephrase. List1 as objects, List2 contains a copy of some object of List1. 
List2 can contain several time the same object. I'd like have a list of the object not present in List2 and 
if present (one or more) the some must be equal the value in list1 (HourBy) if not the object appear in the result 
list with the difference for HourBy between List1 and the List2 (the sum for the Id)

Comment: @MattH : agree, the samples are clearer :)

Comment: @Kris, ok I think I know what it is your trying to do. Let me update my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code, it's not perfect but working and may be clearer for newbie in Linq (like me)

```
List< MyClass> listRes = new List< MyClass>();
foreach ( MyClass item in list1)
{
    var exist = list2
        .Select(x => x.MyClass)
        .Contains(item);

    if (!exist)
        listRes.Add(item);
    else
    {
        var totalFromOther = list2
            .Where(x => x.MyClass.Id == item.Id)
            .Sum(y => y.HourBy);

        if (item.HourBy != totalFromOther)
        {        
            item.HourBy = item.HourBy - totalFromOther;
            listRes.Add(item);
        }            
    }   
}
```

Thanks for you help,

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by the following Linq statement:

```
var result = List1.Where(x => !List2.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id)
    || List2.Single(y => x.Id == y.Id).HourBy < x.HourBy);
```

Best Regards

Comment: Hey Oliver, I created my linq query in my project according to your example It was helped to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after, based on the example lists you supplied...

```
var list3 = new List<MyClass>();

foreach(var item in list1)
{
   var totalFromOther = list2.Where(x => x.id == item.id).Sum(y => y.HourBy);
   var newItem = new MyClass() { id = item.Id, HourBy = item.HourBy - totalFromOther };
   if(newItem.HourBy > 0)
     list3.Add(newItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
        var qry = from ee in
                       (from e1 in list1
                        join e2 in list2 on e1.Id equals e2.Id into gj
                        from e in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { 
                            e1.Id,
                            MainHourBy = e1.HourBy,
                            SecondHourBy = (e == null ? 0 : e.HourBy)
                        })
                   where ee.SecondHourBy < ee.MainHourBy
                   group ee by ee.Id into g
                   select new MyClass
                   {
                       Id = g.Key,
                       HourBy = g.First().MainHourBy - g.Sum(el => el.SecondHourBy)
                   };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var agg1 = from l in list1
           group l by l.ID into g
           select new { g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(_ => _.HourBy) };
var agg2 = from l in list2
           group l by l.ID into g
           select new { g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(_ => _.HourBy) };

var q = from l1 in agg1
        let l2 = agg2.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Key == l1.Key)
        let sum = l1.Sum - (l2 != null ? l2.Sum : 0)
        where sum != 0
        select new MyClass(l1.Key, sum);

var list3 = q.ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the 'let' clause. Is it evaluated once for the query, or once per row in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Group list 2, so there is one entry per ID, with HourBy = total hour by
var summedL2 = from item2 in List2
              group item2 by item2.ID into g
              select new Test(g.Key, g.Sum(item => item.HourBy));

var result = 
            //Select items from list1
             from item1 in List1
             //Left join to our summed List2
             join item2s in summedL2 on item1.ID equals item2s.ID into tempItem2s
             from item2 in tempItem2s.DefaultIfEmpty()
             //Where there is no match, or item2 is < item1
             where (item2 == null || item2.HourBy < item1.HourBy)
             //Select a new Test object, with the HourBy changed
             select new Test(item1.ID, item1.HourBy - (item2 == null ? 0 : item2.HourBy));
```